# How to convert Month(getDate()) into text format in YYYY-MM format?

Tags: sql, postgresql

How to convert Month(getDate()) into text format in YYYY-MM format? (2022-04 for example)

I tried doing this but it doesn't work:

```
SELECT month, b, c, d, count,
CASE WHEN difference >= 0 THEN 'x' ELSE 'a' END as status
FROM strt.view view
WHERE month = MONTH(getDate());
```

the month column is text format, how can I run this query?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I am using postgres sorry!

Comment: `Select to_char(current_date, 'YYYY-MM'); 2022-04`

Comment: @AdrianKlaver sorry I am a noob, like this? SELECT month, b, c, d, count,
CASE WHEN difference >= 0 THEN 'x' ELSE 'a' END as status
FROM strt.view view
WHERE month = Select to_char(current_date, 'YYYY-MM');

Comment: No, `... WHERE month = to_char(current_date, 'YYYY-MM');`